# Changing glossary pagestyle using memoir

Tags: memoir, glossaries

I use the `memoir` class to typeset my documents. This class also allows the easy addition of a glossary to those documents. However, the default pagestyle for the glossary is `plain`. I want to change the pagestyle to the style that I have defined myself and that I have set as the pagestyle for the document using `\pagestyle{myheadings}`. How can I achieve this feat? An [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that/231#231) is included below.

```
\documentclass[twoside,article]{memoir}
\usepackage{authoraftertitle}

\title{foo bar}

\makeindex
\makeglossary

\makepsmarks{myheadings}{%
\createplainmark{glossary}{both}{\glossaryname}
}

\makeevenhead{myheadings}{\textsf\thepage}{}{\textsc{\textsf\MyTitle}} 
\makeoddhead{myheadings}{\textsc{\textsf\MyTitle}}{}{\textsf\thepage}

\pagestyle{myheadings}

\begin{document}

\glossary{foo}{bar}

\printglossary

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates what you've tried.

Comment: I've added an MWE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It uses the same page style as `chapter` so make a different alias for the `chapter` style. Perhaps use

```
\aliaspagestyle{chapter}{myheadings}
```

Though, I find it strange to have a chapter first page with headers (which is why `chapter` is an alias for `plain`)

Comment: this would generally be strange. However, as I am using the `article` option of the `memoir` document class, what is called a _chapter_ is more like a section of most documents produced using the `article` document class.